# deferring with `.load()` and/or ajax stack

Tags: jquery, ajax, deferred

I have a webpage with a drop down list of products and two groups of filters: Type (education, games) and Media (book, cd).  You can select from either filter at any time and the drop down will be filtered accordingly via ajax.  This all works great.

When you select a filter, a throbber is displayed over the drop down until the ajax resolves.  The problem is, if you change the filter more than once before it finishes resolving, the first request removes the throbber and displays the drop down again while the second request is still going.  This is a minor problem that I'd like to fix.  Here is the javascript:

```
     $('.radio-filter-type').change(function() {
        $("#products-list").hide();
        $("#products-throbber").show();
        $("#products-container").load(window.location + ' #products-list',
           $("#filter-type").serialize() + '&medium=' + $("#filter-media
              input[name=medium]:checked").val()
           , function () {
              $("#products-list").show();
              $("#products-throbber").hide();
           }
        );
     });
```

Obviously, a radio button changes in the meantime, the first `.load()` will resolve, show the list and hide the throbber before the other one finishes.  I can do something like this:

```
reqCount = 0;
...
.change( ...
   reqCount++;
   .load( ...
      , function () {
         reqCount--;
         if (!reqCount) { //show list and hide throbber
```

However with `Deferred` I feel like there has to be a cleaner way.  Is there any way to add requests to a current Deffered stack and wait until they all resolve (they can be added at arbitrary times).  I also notice that `.load().then()` does not seem to work.  Can `Deferred` be used with `.load()` at all?  I use `.load()` because you can specify the DOM element to be returned only, which is convenient.  If not, is there any other way to manage current ajax requests and perform an action only when they have all completed at once?

Comment: jQuery.load does not return a deferred so you can't actually use it as such.  You'll have to switch to $.get or $.post or $.ajax

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to cancel the last filter request and start a new one if the user changes the filter variables?  Or do you actually want to queue them and display each one in order?

Comment: @BenL either way works .. how do you cancel the other request?  And if I can't use `.load()` can I still do simple DOM filtering with `.get()`?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just disable the filter inputs while the ajax post is in progress? Not quite as nice but solves your problem.

```
$('.radio-filter-type').change(function() {
    $("#products-list").hide();
    $("#products-throbber").show();
    //disable checkbox
    $("#filter-media input[name=medium]).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#products-container").load(window.location + ' #products-list',
       $("#filter-type").serialize() + '&medium=' + $("#filter-media
          input[name=medium]:checked").val()
       , function () {
          $("#products-list").show();
          $("#products-throbber").hide();
          //renable checkbox
          $("#filter-media input[name=medium]).removeAttr('disabled');
       }
    );
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this is by canceling the actions at the successful conclusion of the ajax request if the value of the filter is different than what it was upon the original request. Here's a try at what that code might look like:

```
$('.radio-filter-type').change(function() {
    var filterStateAtChange = $("#filter-media input[name=medium]).is(':checked');

    $("#products-list").hide();
    $("#products-throbber").show();
    $.get(window.location + ' #products-list',
        $("#filter-type").serialize() + '&medium=' + $("#filter-media
          input[name=medium]:checked").val()
       , 
      function (html) {
          //cancel (do nothing) if the value of the checkbox now is not equal to what it was when request originated
          if (filterStateAtChange === $("#filter-media input[name=medium]).is(':checked')) {
              $("#products-container").html(html)
              $("#products-list").show();
              $("#products-throbber").hide();
          }

       }
    );
 });
```

Comment: I'll post an addendum with the html since I don't think you understand it..but I'm too busy eating turkey right now